# Weird acting for loop

Tags: python

My for loop is acting weird. I want to get a name of members in a team but instead of it I am getting only one last name triple. Can you please say me where can be the problem?

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.members = []        

    def add_member(self, member):
        self.member = member
        self.members.append(team.member)

def print_team(team):
    list_members= []
    for member in team.members:
        list_members.append(team.member.name)

    print (list_members)

team = Team('Wolves')
team.add_member(Animal('Josh'))
team.add_member(Animal('Janette'))
team.add_member(Animal('Peter'))
print_team(team)
```

I am getting -> Peter, Peter, Peter

I want to get -> Josh, Janette, Peter

Comment: Replace `self.members.append(team.member)` with `self.members.append(member)` and remove the previous line. `team` uses the global variable with the same name.

Comment: This does not make sense! print_team should be a function inside the class Team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose of line `self.member = member` in `add_member`? That sets object's property `.member` to last added member. Use name like `.last_added`.
Or use `def add_member(self, member): self.members.append(member)`
, what appends directly the object passed when the function was called.

However, that's not important for me. In loop, you need to change `list_members.append(team.member.name)` to `list_members.append(member.name)`. You were adding that last member added, as mentioned above. When you change it, you will add the member you got in loop. This will make the difference more significant:

```
def print_team(team):

    list_private_to_func = []
    for object in team.members:
        list_private_to_func.append(object.name)

    print(list_private_to_func)
```

And yeah, @Anton vBR has much better approach to this question!

Answer (score 3):

For readability you should always attempt to put class-related stuff like print functions inside the class itself. So how about doing this:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.members = []        

    def add_member(self, member):
        self.members.append(member)

    def print_team(self):
        print([i.name for i in team.members])

    def __str__(self):
        return str([i.name for i in team.members])

def print_team():
    print([i.name for i in team.members])

team = Team('Wolves')
team.add_member(Animal('Josh'))
team.add_member(Animal('Janette'))
team.add_member(Animal('Peter'))

print_team() # option 1 - outside - not recommended
team.print_team() # option 2 - inside
print(team) # option 3 - inside using __str__ (best I'd say)
```

Prints this 3 times:

```
['Josh', 'Janette', 'Peter']
```

Comment: This could go but what if I want to have function for that?

Comment: @RoseAnn I made one "normal function" and used the "str function". Or do you mean you want a normal function outside the class?

Comment: @RoseAnn Done, but nothing I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You are using team.member.name in print_team. it always takes last initialize value of team.member.

You can also sort your function,
There is no need use loop in print_team().
just save member.name in add_memeber function.

```
    class Animal:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    class Team:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.members = []        

        def add_member(self, member):
            self.member = member
            self.members.append(member.name)

    def print_team(team):
        print team.members


    team = Team('Wolves')
    team.add_member(Animal('Josh'))
    team.add_member(Animal('Janette'))
    team.add_member(Animal('Peter'))
    print_team(team)
```